# bootstrap columns not working in react js application

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

My `bootstrap column` classes are not working.

It's coming in a single line.

**My code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


import axios from 'axios';

class PLPMenu extends Component {

  state = {
    shoeCategory: []
  }



  componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'GirlShoeCategory'

    axios.get(`http://localhost:3030/${url}`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data.express.catalogEntryView);
        this.setState({
          shoeCategory: res.data.express.catalogEntryView
        })
      })
  }

  render() {
    const { shoeCategory } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>

        {
          shoeCategory.map(shoeList => (
            <div className="container">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-4">

                  <h2 key={shoeList.uniqueID}></h2>

                  <Link to="/PDP"><p className="pdp">{shoeList.name}</p></Link>

                </div>

              </div>

            </div>
          ))
        }



      </div>


    )

  }

}

export default PLPMenu;
```

index.css

```
.header{
  display:inline-flex;
  vertical-align: top;
  list-style-type: none;

}

.header .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;    
  border: none;
  color: #111;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  margin: 0;
  background: inherit;
}

.header:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #00b5cc;
}


.dropdown-content {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content li a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content li a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.header:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.drop-button {
  font-size: 16px;    
  border: none;
  color: #111;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  margin: 0;
  background: inherit;
}

.sub-menu{
  list-style-type: none;
  display:none;
}

.dropdown-content:hover .submenu{
 background-color: red;
}
.dropdown-content li:hover .sub-menu { 

  display: block; 

}

.pdp{
  height:200px;
  background-color: #ddd;

 width: 350px;

}

img{ 
    width:100%;
  }
```

[image]

I have **imported bootstrap classes** in the `App.js` file

> import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

but still the bootstrap columns classes are not working. Can anybody please help me on this. I'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: Can you verify if any other Boostrap css has been loaded correctly? Perhaps, you didn't configure the Bootstrap correctly.

Comment: It's not working at all......But how would I configure. I have imported the bootstrap.min.css

Comment: @SajjadTabreez check in the sources tab of your devtools that sheets are actually loading on the page

Comment: It worked at last......I have put the container and row outside.....and column class inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your error here is that when you map your data, you include the `.row` div. You might want to try this:

```
  <div>
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        {
          shoeCategory.map(shoeList => (
            <div className="col-md-4">
              <h2 key={shoeList.uniqueID}></h2>
              <Link to="/PDP"><p className="pdp">{shoeList.name}</p></Link>
            </div>
          ))
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: But, using single row to contain I think more or less 4 items could be problematic. In case your run into this issue, check [this out](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#equal-width-multi-row)